# Java - Put else statement in looping for

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to make the handling of which if the data I input is not found. However, when the data is not found, the program will print a message else as much repetition. Where should I put the else statement correctly?

```
public void Data(String x){
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table1[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table2[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table2[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table3[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table3[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table4[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table4[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table5[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table5[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table6[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table6[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table7[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table7[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("Data not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current `else` statement?

Comment: Are you saying you want to break out of the whole function if the data wasn't found on the first loop iteration, instead of repeating 5 times?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the expression evaluates to false, the program will execute else. But, it will be printed 5 times

Comment: @NicholasSmith yeah. That's I mean

Comment: Have you heard of using `break` to terminate a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void Data(String x){
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table1[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table2[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table2[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table3[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table3[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table4[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table4[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table5[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table5[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table6[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table6[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(table7[i][1])){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.printf("|%-40s", table7[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else b = true;
    }
    if (b) System.out.println("Data not found!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to terminate as soon as data is not found, you can change your else statement to this:

```
else {
    System.out.println("Data not found!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Or as Tim pointed out, you could use `break` instead of `return` if you have other code after the loop you needed to execute.